# CSS3 Outline dashed border on one side only

Tags: css, outline

I want to add a right dashed border using outline. I am aware that I can't do it in just one side with this property.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: rectangle]

I tried using shadow-box, but it doesn't work if the border is dashed.

Thanks

```
width: 125px;
height: 160px;
background-color: #edb103;
outline: 2px dashed #0b0000;
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using border-right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use border-right, putting the outline around the `::after` pseudo-element might be a solution...

```css
div {
  width: 125px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #edb103;
}

div::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 158px;
  content: '';
  position:relative; left:125px; top:1px;
  outline: 1px dashed #0b0000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```